# What am I doing wrong ? $\int \csc(x) \cot^2 (x) dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

$$
\int \csc(x)\cot^2(x) dx= \int \csc(x) (\csc^2 (x) - 1) dx = \int (\csc^3(x) - \csc(x))dx
$$

Integrating by parts:

let u = $\csc(x)$, then du = $-\csc(x)\cot(x)dx$.

let dv = $\csc^2 (x)dx$, then v = $-\cot(x)$.

The above integral becomes

$$\int \csc(x)\cot^2(x) dx=-\csc(x)\cot(x) - \int \csc(x)\cot^2 (x)dx - \int \csc(x) dx.$$

Using $\cot^2 (x) = \csc^2 (x) - 1$ identity:

$$\int \csc(x)\cot^2(x) dx= -\csc(x)\cot(x) - \int \csc^3(x)dx + \int \csc(x) dx - \int \csc(x) dx\\
=-\frac{1}{2} \csc(x)\cot(x) - \frac{1}{2}\ln |\csc(x) + \cot(x)| + \ln |\csc(x) + \cot(x)|\\
=-\frac{1}{2} \csc(x)\cot(x) + \frac{1}{2}\ln |\csc(x) + \cot(x)| + C$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just the last, as your try, you need to find $\int \csc^3(x)dx$, and $$\int \csc^3(x)dx \neq -\frac{1}{2}\csc x\cot x$$
so the last part is wrong.

Comment: Oh! Thank you , I got it

Comment: @user349557 after your edit, the $\int\csc^3xdx$ part is still wrong. my solution as \begin{align*}
\int\csc^3xdx &= - \int\csc xd(\cot x)\\
&= -\csc x\cot x+\int\cot xd(\csc x)\\
&= -\csc x\cot x+\int\cot x \cdot (-\csc x\cot x)dx\\
&= -\csc x\cot x-\int\csc x\cot^2xdx\\
&= -\csc x\cot x-\int\csc x \cdot (\csc^2x-1)dx\\
&= -\csc x\cot x-\int\csc^3xdx+\int\csc xdx
\end{align*}
so
$$2\int\csc^3xdx = -\csc x\cot x+\int\csc xdx$$
then
$$\int\csc^3xdx = -\frac{1}{2}\csc x\cot x+\frac{1}{2}\log|\csc x - \cot x|$$

Comment: The rule of thumb for integration according to my prof is that wolfram is always right, and it got the same answer as me. As well as this tool: http://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: @user349557 you are right, that is my mistake, you are not wrong, sorry.